# Validating Symfony3 form with Command not Entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, command

I have prepared a simple application with symfony3.2 and use of DDD (at least I tried). But I have problems validating ProductType form, which uses NewProductCommand instad of Product object.
My form is:

```
<?php
namespace AdminBundle\Form;
use Shop\Domain\Command\NewProductCommand;
use AppBundle\Form\PriceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataMapperInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
/**
 * Product add form
 *
 * @package AdminBundle\Form
 */
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Building form
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'name',
                TextType::class,
                array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Nazwa',
//                    'constraints' => [new NotBlank(), new Length(['max' => 255])],
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'description',
                TextareaType::class,
                array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Opis',
                    'attr' => [
                        'rows' => 10
                    ],
//                    'constraints' => [new Length(['min' => 100, 'max' => 65000])],
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'price',
                PriceType::class,
                array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Cena'
                )
            );
    }
    /**
     * Options configuration
     *
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => NewProductCommand::class
            )
        );
    }
    /**
     * Return form name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'product';
    }
}
```

And in controller I have:

```
    $command = new NewProductCommand();
    $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $command);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
```

The validation works when I remove commented constraints, but what I want to achieve is that the form uses my Product class validators.

I think that the problem is that, I pass here NewProductCommand::class, and not the Product::class, so the form doesn't know anything about Product class (which is defined in doctrine orm product mapping: https://github.com/wojto/washop/blob/master/src/Shop/Infrastructure/Repository/Doctrine/config/mapping/Product.orm.yml) and validation, which is in yml too (https://github.com/wojto/washop/blob/master/src/AdminBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml).

Where is the place, I should connect NewProductCommand with Product class so the form can use validation for Product class?

I hope, I make it clear ;) full app code is here: https://github.com/wojto/washop/

Maybe I am doing everything wrong, so I appreciate any help :)

Comment: If you want it to be a valid `Product` you should just tell the form it's for the `Product` class and pass it a `Product` reference?

Comment: It will be the simplest solution, but it won't be Command Query Separation anymore. I found similar topics here https://github.com/webdevilopers/php-ddd/issues/5 but without a clear answer. I guess it all comes to "where to validate commands in Symfony" :/